# Reveal a HTML Div Via Animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a semi-circular div, which will have some content. It will be rendered but not visible to start with (using Angular 2). On a certain user action, hovering over another section of the screen, the div will appear, but I don't want to just use display:none/block, or hidden.

What I'm trying to do is have another div with similar css act as a mask and slide up to reveal the semi-circle div.

I have tried numerous ways, and it would be of no advantage to post that code here. I have animated it by changing it's position so it moves into view, but it seems like a ridiculous way to do it.

```
    <div class="semi-circle">
      <button class="add-button" >Add</button>
    </div>

    .semi-circle{
         height:80px;
         width:160px;
         border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
         -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
         -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
         background:green;
    }
    .add-button{
        position:absolute;
        left: 65px;
        top: 50px;
    }
```

[This is basically what it will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZODj.png)

Comment: as a generic suggestion, `translate` is a much more performant choice than animating `position` left/right/top/bottom values

Comment: Can you use [an external library](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) ? It will save you lots of time.

Comment: @ODelibalta Hi. I want the semi-circle to be revealed in it's current position i.e. from invisible to visible with another semi-circle acting as the clip area - that way it will look like it's expanding outs itself, and not just moving in one lump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect in CSS alone, with an `::after` pseudo-element and a `transition`:

```css
.semi-circle {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width:160px;
height:80px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.semi-circle::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 80px;
left: 0;
width:160px;
height:80px;
background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
transform: translateY(0);
transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

p {
display: inline-block;
width: 160px;
text-align: center;
}

p:hover ~ .semi-circle::after {
transform: translateY(-80px);
}
```

```html
<p>Hover me</p>
<div class="semi-circle"></div>
```

Comment: that's close indeed. But as the translateY happens, the div expands with a straight edge along the top. The reason I expect I will need a second div is that I want it to appear with the same curve, not a straight edge along the top

Comment: That's because a white semi-circle is moving upwards to reveal a green semi-circle beneath. The straight edge you can see is the bottom of the white semi-circle moving upwards :-)

Comment: I've changed it (very slightly) so that a green semi-circle is now moving upwards to eclipse a white semi-circle.

Comment: I don't think this will work now that I look into it. The div might be placed above text, other components, or any colored background. It's going to be going from transparent to visible

Comment: I have changed the `background-color` of `.semi-circle` from `rgb(255,255,255)` (white) to `rgba(0,0,0,0)` (transparent).

Comment: You have some serious styling skills @Rounin !! I'm only a few months into a switch from ActionScript programming to JavaScript, after 6 yrs of ActionScript, and the CSS aspect is probably the biggest challenge!

Comment: Keep persevering, @Colin - you'll get there. I started learning CSS2 in 2003, but... I only started learning CSS3 in 2011. Even then, I only started using `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements (and `@media` queries) in Jan 2015, CSS transitions in summer 2015, CSS `@keyframes` in December 2015 and CSS `flexbox` last week. So just keep learning something new every couple of months and you'll get there. (StackOverflow is my favourite place on the web for learning and practising).